# Id selector is formatted weirdly

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Sorry for the title, but I don't know how to call this question. I'm using id as selector to format my ajax. But one of my div have a special format, and I don't know why. Moreover, the format generated, can't be include into my js file.

Normally the div is formated as following:

```
<div id= 'post_iter(<%=@post.id%>)'></div>
```

And when I inspect the file, the div is marked as #post_iter(4)

But when I try to copy the path, I have something like that:

```
#post_iter\28 4\29
```

Comment: is the problem that you can't inclue it in your JS? If so can you post what you're trying to put in the js so we can see the context of what's going wrong? and do you get any errors in your browser console?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: `\28` is char `(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The special characters are taking because of the braces

Instead of the braces try using

```
<div id= 'post_iter_<%=@post.id%>'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips @kajal ojha, I've never heard about this particularity.

Comment: @stigGaret My pleasure mate  :)

Answer (score -1):

`<%=@post.id%>` is ASP code, so theres that you have to take into consideration. So it gets prcessed to `4` from what you get.

Comment: Easily mixup between ASP and Ruby on Rails, RoR: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940871/ruby-on-rails-using-javascript-variable-in-tags-in-html-erb , ASP tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags

Comment: They both use `<% ... %>`

Comment: But this question is not *ASP* and your answer *doesn't solve the problem*!

Comment: Ohhhh, okay i missed seeing the `ruby-on-rails` tag, the only thing that lets you know it uses `ruby-on-rails`